# Implementing a delay/refresh in OpenGL animation

Tags: c, opengl, animation, delay, glut

I'm studying some very basic 3D rendering using opengl, but my teacher uses a pc under wich you can use the sleep() function for rendering each of the animation's frames.

However when i try to do the same thing on my mac i only get the last frame. if i use the sleep() function my mac goes literally to sleep mode.

I've read something about an NSTimer but i don't know how to implement it.

Here's my code, it works just fine on a pc, i only want to replace the commented **sleep()** with a mac equivalent that enables me to see each frame during that delay

```
#include<OpenGL/gl.h>
#include<OpenGL/glu.h>
#include<GLUT/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void init (void)
{
glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
gluLookAt(0,4,4,0,0,0,0,1,0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluPerspective(90,1,1,12);
}
void Cubes(void)
{
int i=0;
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glutInitDisplayMode(GL_DEPTH);
for (i=0; i<360;i++)
{
    glRotated(1,1,0,0);
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glutSolidSphere(1,20,20);
    glColor3f(0.8,0.8,0);
    glutWireSphere(1,20,20);
    glColor3f(0,0,1);
    glutSolidTorus(1,2,40,40);
    glFlush();
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    //Sleep(20);
}
}
int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitWindowSize(600,600);
glutCreateWindow("Depth Buffer");
init();
glutDisplayFunc(Cubes);
glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Please tell your teacher that he is doing it wrong!** To do a animation with GLUT don't put a animation loop into the display function, but register a idle function, that reissues a display. Also this code misses a buffer swap (which is mandatory on MacOS X if not running in full screen mode, to tell the compositor you're done with rendering).

Also you shouldn't sleep for an animation (the buffer swap will do this anyway) but measure the time between frames.

---

#### Update: Fixed code

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double getftime(
    void )
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec*1e-6;
}

static double lasttime;

void display(
    void )
{
    int width, height;
    double finishtime, delta_t;

    static float angle = 0;

    width = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    height = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    glClearColor( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0 );
    /* combine the clearing flags for more efficient operation */
    glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective( 90, (float)width/(float)height, 1, 12 );

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt( 0, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 );

    glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    glRotated( angle, 1, 0, 0 );
    glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 );
    glutSolidSphere( 1, 20, 20 );
    glColor3f( 0.8, 0.8, 0 );
    glutWireSphere( 1, 20, 20 );
    glColor3f( 0, 0, 1 );
    glutSolidTorus( 1, 2, 40, 40 );
    glDisable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );

    glutSwapBuffers();

    finishtime = getftime();
    delta_t = finishtime - lasttime;

    angle = fmodf(angle + 10*delta_t, 360);

    lasttime = finishtime;
}
int main(
    int argc,
    char **argv )
{
    glutInit( &argc, argv );
    glutInitWindowSize( 600, 600 );
    /* glutInitDisplayMode must be called before glutCreateWindow, flags are prefixed with GLUT_ not GL */
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE );
    glutCreateWindow( "Depth Buffer" );
    glutDisplayFunc( display );
    /* register glutPostRedisplay for continuous animation */
    glutIdleFunc(glutPostRedisplay);

    lasttime = getftime();
    glutMainLoop(  );
}
```

Comment: Yeaaah about that she doesn't really care about teaching :/ she focuses more on screwing us the most she can +_+ and according to her if i call swapbuffers() i have an "unfair advantage" over my mates wtf.. Anyway can you link me somewhere i can read about this reissuing of the display function? I need to find a way to animate nevertheless using her code ...

Comment: Yay thanks i'll check this code out u just did more teaching than my teacher in the whole quarter lol

Comment: @CheyBarrett: " she focuses more on screwing" Sounds like a good reason to ace the test/subject for me.

Comment: @datenwolf: It's been a while since I used GLUT, but if I remember correctly, it makes sense to use `sleep(1)` and similar functions within idle to prevent program from hogging CPU (or CPU core) - if platform has vsync disabled. Of course, using sleep() instead of measuring time between frames is a bad idea...

Comment: @SigTerm: This hogging of the CPU is just a misrepresentation of the Windows Task Manager, that considers blocking as "using CPU". Adding the Sleep(1) is just a workaround for Windows to report a CPU utilization that makes sense.

Comment: @CheyBarrett: If you like to, refer your techer to me. Maybe do this in a Skype call in front of the class. The way she does it is very bad style and as a teacher you shouldn't promote bad habits. Also as you found out on some systems you must call SwapBuffers for things to show up. Last but not least: Her code seemed to attempt to draw to the front buffer. But for this she should have called glFinish() instead of glFlush().

Comment: @datenwolf: As far as I know, this is not a misrepresentation, and application will actually all available CPU Resources heating up cpu. However this will be only true if event loop doesn't "wait" for anything anywhere - i.e. uses "PeekMessage" and vsync is disabled, so any kind of idle processing will be close to "busy-waiting". Also, if I remember correctly `Sleep(1)` will actually wait for 10 millisecond.

Comment: @SigTerm: If vsync is enables (which it should be) then the program does not consume any CPU time while blocking at SwapBuffers, except if there're additional threads running.

Comment: @datenwolf: I explicitly mentioned "if vsync is disabled".

Comment: @SigTerm: Well, you shouldn't disable vsync. There's simply no point in trying to render faster than the monitor can display it.

Comment: This code taught me so much, and saved me a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I concur with the above posts that your teacher is wrong. However, to answer your question, use usleep(useconds_t useconds) to sleep on mac os x.  here's the man page:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/usleep.3.html

note that the sleep time is in microseconds instead of milliseconds like it is on windows.  Also note that like on windows, it will sleep *at least* the time specified. It might sleep a whole lot longer, which is one of the many reasons you shouldn't use it but should measure the time between frames and update appropriately instead.

Cheers!